# Torch Error: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, text-to-speech

Am new to stackoverflow forum, so please bear if I make some mistake in the format of asking doubts.

Am trying to run this code: (I think there is problem with torch, don't know for sure)

```
# Imports used through the rest of the notebook.
import torch
import torchaudio
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import IPython

from tortoise.api import TextToSpeech
from tortoise.utils.audio import load_audio, load_voice, load_voices

# This will download all the models used by Tortoise from the HuggingFace hub.

tts = TextToSpeech()
```

but am getting error like:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18216\2126429222.py in <module>
      1 # Imports used through the rest of the notebook.
      2 import torch
----> 3 import torchaudio
      4 import torch.nn as nn
      5 import torch.nn.functional as F

c:\Users\gl471f\Downloads\pdoc\Boeing_ML\other models\boeing_tts\.venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from torchaudio import (  # noqa: F401
      2     _extension,
      3     compliance,
      4     datasets,
      5     functional,

c:\Users\gl471f\Downloads\pdoc\Boeing_ML\other models\boeing_tts\.venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension.py in <module>
    133 
    134 
--> 135 _init_extension()
    136 _check_cuda_version()

c:\Users\gl471f\Downloads\pdoc\Boeing_ML\other models\boeing_tts\.venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension.py in _init_extension()
    103                     pass
    104 
...
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

My specs are

- NVIDIA RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU
- cuda available is true - 10.0
- python - 3.7.9
- pytorch - pip install torch==1.3.1 torchvision==0.4.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
- tensorflow - pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0

Comment: you didn't install the module `torchaudio`

Comment: I did install, still same error persist

Comment: "Asking doubts" is not technically a "mistake" but you might prefer the more idiomatic "asking questions"; outside of India, a "doubt" is a suspicion that something is wrong, i.e. a feeling which might or might not provoke you to ask a question.